# Node.js - Why does my project says can't find module when it is installed globally

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I installed express globally using the command "npm install -g express". I verified express is present in my /usr/local/bin/" directory.

However every time i create a new project and execute it says "Can't find module express".

When i install express locally using the command "npm install express" it works. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [npm FAQ](http://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html#I-installed-something-globally-but-I-can-t-require-it), globally-installed packages are only used for runnung the executables; they're not used in your projects, for projects to be self-contained entities not depending on the environment.

Also, if you have `express` installed globally, you can create a new `express`-based project using `express` command (see the "Quick Start" section of the [`express` guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html)), it will save you from doing `npm install express` manually.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought i was making a mistake by installing the dependencies every time.

Comment: Theoretically, framework authors have only two options: to force every application to carry all its dependencies and configurations with it (with only core being shared between the projects), or to allow applications to use some global (yet machine-specific) libraries pool. The latter has a lot of disadvantages related to versions management and custom libraries (not enlisted in npmjs.org) usage. The former allows you to run your application on any machine that has an appropriate (or not so appropriate) Node.js version installed, no matter what libraries do you use.